# Can I install Yosemite on a different Mac with another Apple ID

Tags: macos, mac, install

Can I use a copy of OS X Yosemite installer to install Yosemite on a Mac owned by someone else who obviously has a different Apple ID?

Comment: If you send your MacBook in to Apple for repair, and they replace the SSD, they will automatically install the latest OS that is compatible with the computer. So from that, you can reasonably infer that Apple could care less about which Apple ID was used to install an OS version.

Comment: Yes you can depending on the model.

Answer (score -1):

Yosemite should be a free upgrade.

You can also download it for free here.

https://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/48498/os-x-yosemite

Comment: The download link on MacUpdate points to the App Store where OSX Yosemite is no longer available, at least if you are already on a newer macOS version.

Comment: I "purchased" Yosemite for free on my macbook so was able to download it from the app store. 
I don't want it for my own mac, but for a friend who is on snow leopard and has never upgraded even though she sent it apple for a full service on several occasions.

Comment: The link I posted has it for free, which is why I posted it.